# how to create a proxy service which calls a class mediator which accepts JSON request

Tags: wso2

My requirement is to transform a JSON request to a XML format. 
And I got the code which converts JSON to XML in the below URL.
https://isurugunawardana.com/2015/05/19/json-support-for-wso2-esb-class-mediator/

But i need to know how this is been called from a proxy service in WSO2 EI..
I have tried creating a proxy service which calls the class mediator.
 '

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="TestClassMedProxy"
       startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       transports="http,https">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="BEGIN" value="Begin Sequence"/>
         </log>
         <class name="org.anthem.caremore.JSONtoXML">
            <property name="inputPath" value="5"/>
         </class>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

`

Comment: Can you provide some additional details about your question?

Comment: I want to have API which invokes the class mediator which converts the JSON request and gives back the XML format as the response.

Comment: To convert a given json to XML, you can just use Content-Type and messageType properties to application/xml. WSO2 has inbuilt message formatter and builder which will do the transformation parts. I don't think you need a class mediator to do it. <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/xml"/>
    <property name="ContentType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/xml"/>

Comment: Can you post the complete API sample code here? I tried the same but it did not work for me.